# MS sql update in few tables - all or nothing

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need edit some php system (not my code) which work with mssql.
The goal is update few tables in mssql while ensuring execute all or nothig. So if in third update error occurs i need roll back all changes.

```
$query = '';
// tried transaction
// $query .= "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"; 

$query .= "UPDATE table1 SET qr = " . $newQrNumber . " WHERE id = " . $userId . " ;";
$query .= "UPDATE table2 SET qr = " . $newQrNumber . " WHERE id = " . $userId. " ;";
$query .= "UPDATE table3 SET qr = " . $newQrNumber . " WHERE id = " . $userId. " ;";

// tried transaction
// $query .= "COMMIT;"; 

 // $this->db = mssql_connect($server, $usr, $pwd); - only for show what is in $this->db
 // executing query
 mssql_query($query, $this->db);
```

But i have error message:

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. (severity 16)

Without transactions is query ok. What i doing wrong?

Comment: I think the code in question is little diferent from real code ...  `$query = "BEGIN TRANSACTION;";` rewrite the value of variable `$query = "COMMIT;";` too.

Comment: yes true... fixed